# Who is responsible for the scene involving Bruce and Barbara in 2016 "The Killing Joke"?

Tags: dc, batman, behind-the-scenes, the-killing-joke-2016

I was very surprised to see a

> sex scene between Batman and Batgirl

given that it was the genius Bruce Timm directing the movie, with legends such as Mark Hamill and Kevin Conroy reprising their parts.

The scene seemed a bit off from the overall story, not to mention that a sexual and romantic relationship between Barbara and Bruce isn't a very popular one.

All of this got me wondering whether it was actually Timm's idea to include this scene. Has there been any statement on that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SciFi & Fantasy SE. Can you please clean up the profanity from your question, as well as the grammar, spelling, and formatting?

Comment: Also, can you edit the title to better match what you are trying to ask, and format the text in your question to emphasize the question better?

Comment: Edit to exclude rant and profanity; feel free to revert back if you find this too intrusive, but also try to be more specific and on-point in your questions.

Comment: Doesn't look like a dupe to me, the linked question asks about the reasoning for why they included Batgirl scenes in general, this one asks specifically who's idea it was for the two to have sex.

Comment: That edit was alot better, not intrusive at all.

Comment: My pleasure, any time.

Comment: On a side note, this is a legitimate question (aside from looking like a duplicate), and not worth the downvotes (now that it's edited)

Comment: I've retracted my downvote now.

Comment: @Gallifreian: Agreed. Downvote retracted, thanks for the edits.

Comment: @DBPriGuy  -  maybe you could vote to reopen then? I feel bad for voting as a dupe, those turn out to be different questions after all.

Comment: Because they wanted to keep that R rating.

Comment: @iMerchant exactly. Suddenly everybody wants R superhero movies. Rather than making, you know, actual content for adults, they treat it like twelve year olds trying to write something really adult. Bad language. Sex. Maybe some violence. Disappointing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this site](https://www.inverse.com/article/18695-batgirl-batman-sex-scene-killing-joke-joker-alan-moore) the decision was made by Alan Burnett, Bruce Timm, and Brian Azzarello together:

> The decision for the two superheroes have casual sex, made by Bruce Timm, Alan Burnett, and screenwriter Brian Azzarello, changes several aspects of both the character’s histories, and twists the film’s overall interpretation of Alan Moore’s infamous comic. Although a sexual or romantic relationship between the two had been teased in some ancillary Batman canon projects (specifically in Batman Beyond), their union is not a mainstay in Gotham stories. Still, director Bruce Timm defended the decision to put in a Wayne-Gordon sex scene.
>
> “It was really important to us to show that both of the characters make some pretty big mistakes. I mean, his ‘parental skills’ aren’t that great,” Timm told Vulture. “Maybe never having had any kids of his own, he doesn’t realize that if you tell a kid to not do something, they’re going to want to do it even more. And then she makes some mistakes and then he kind of overreacts to her mistakes and then she overreacts to his overreaction. So it’s very human; it’s a very understandable story.”

In the [interview](http://www.vulture.com/2016/07/batman-the-killing-joke-sexual-violence.html?mid=twitter_vulture) the site links to Timm says this specifically, although tentatively lays the initial idea at the feet of Brian Azzerello:

> **I'm guessing there will be a lot of conversation after the movie's release about the sex scene. At what point in the creative process did you come up with that idea?**
>
> It came from a three-way conversation between [co-producer] Alan Burnett, [screenwriter] Brian Azzarello, and myself. I don't remember who initially came up with the idea, but we all kind of jumped on it all at the same time and said, Yeah, that's kind of where we need to go. My memory kind of says it was Brian, maybe, who came up with the idea. But I'm not sure.

Of course, it should be noted that Azzarello did **not** work on the earlier incarnations of animated Batman with Bruce Timm and Alan Burnett, such as **Batman Beyond** (where both co-developed and produced the series), which included as backstory that Bruce and Barbara once had a relationship, and **Batman: Mystery of the Batwoman** (written by Burnett) which also had some indications of a relationship, or at least attraction.  So although Azzarello *might* have been the first one to say it at that table, it's also possible that he got the idea from the other two there and their prior work, and merely was the one to voice the idea that they should put it on-screen in this particular movie.

Comment: `infamous comic`?!

Comment: Hey, I just quoted, didn't write it.  I think it does have a share of infamy along with it's fame though, even Moore himself regrets aspects of it.

Comment: I still wouldn't call it infamous though. Controversial, yes, but not outright infamous. Also, thanks for this answer, voted to reopen the question.

Comment: `Still, director Bruce Timm defended the decision to put in a Wayne-Gordon sex scene.` And, after several hours of debate and 2 orders of take-away food, the three of them finally agreed on "Barbara"